# Does updating a time-based workflow affect the current queue?

Tags: administration, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

We have several time-based workflows and the queue has a couple of hundred actions pending. We need to update the selection criteria without emptying the queue. My questions are:

1. If the criteria are updated, will the pending actions that meet the new criteria stay in the queue?
2. Does it matter how I update the criteria? My preference is to use Change Sets but I can do it manually if that is safer.
3. Are there any other caveats about updating time-based workflows that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The pending actions in the queue will not be affected.  In fact, the pending actions int eh queue that don't match the new criteria will remain in the queue.  The criteria is only checked upon entry to the queue.  changing the entry criteria doesn't effect those actions that already made it into the queue.  I have been burned on this before.
2. IMO, technically, it really doesn't matter.  Change sets would be faster
3. See my answer to 1.  This is definitely a caveat.  Changing the criteria only effects newly evaluated records.  The actions already in the queue stay int eh queue even if they don't match the newly updated criteria.  As I said this has tripped me up in the past

Hope that Helps

Comment: One more bit that has tripped me up - you can't convert Leads if the lead is in a time-based workflow queue; you'll need to edit the lead so it removes itself from the queue before you can convert the lead

Comment: In addition, on (3), you can't add or remove actions from a time-dependent workflow rule if it's active, so you have to deactivate it first.